# parameter substitution in pig

Tags: apache-pig, bigdata

```
students = load '/home/vm4learning/Desktop/students-db.txt' using PigStorage('|') as (rnum, sname, name, age, gender, class, subject, marks);
```

I am facing syntax error while using parameter substitution for /home/vm4learning/Desktop/students-db.txt. 
So what is the correct command with proper syntax to use here.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the syntax error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the HDFS path to your Pig LOAD script

First you need to copy your input file in HDFS then you can specify the hdfs path in your pig script

You can use hadoop put command to copy your input file into HDFS using:

```
hadoop fs -put /home/vm4learning/Desktop/students-db.txt /user/input
```

then you can use that path in your pig script

```
students = load '/user/input/students-db.txt' using PigStorage('|') as (.....);
```

---

### UPDATE:

save your pig scripts in a file with extention .pig file.

**process.pig:**

```
students = load '$inputPath' using PigStorage('|') as (.....);
```

Now from terminal you can issue the following command to execute your pig file by passing your input path as argument:

```
pig -p inputPath=/user/input/students-db.txt process.pig
```

For more details you can [check here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/cont.html#Parameter-Sub)

Comment: I know this but I want to replace '/user/input/students-db.txt' path with a parameter say input. this can be achieved using parameter substitution. So there is a command for  parameter substitution something like : pig -param input = '/user/input/students-db.txt'. But am facing syntax error in this command.

Answer (score 1):

use pig -x filename dryrun  -param key=value -param key2=value2